# Application won't run on active device (Samsug Galaxy grand 2)

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest, device

I have a problem wherein I can't run my project on my device, I use an active device because pc is slow. My project is a simple calculator and it should run from android 2.3.3 up to 4.2 jellybean. I've set the minimum required sdk API 10 android 2.3.3 Gingerbread and the target API 18 Android 4.3 Jellybean. Also should I compile it with API 10 android 2.3.3? or API 18 Android 4.1 Jellybean? So I've chosen still the API 10 android 2.3.3 and I created this class.

```
package main;

import com.Foracles.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Main extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

THE XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/upperback">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/sin">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tan">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cos">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ln">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ex">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/log">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/e">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/squareroot">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ce">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/c">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/seven">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/eight">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/nine">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/divide">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/multiply">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/four">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/five">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/six">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/subtract">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/subtract">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/decimal">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/zero">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/sign">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/equal">
    </ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/del">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MANIFEST:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Foracles"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>

</manifest>
```

First I got the error about buffer exception etc. then I searched it on the net said I should add support library from android tools and it is done. But when I run it it says this:

```
[2014-06-13 12:06:39 - Foracles] Performing sync
[2014-06-13 12:06:39 - Foracles] Uploading Foracles.apk onto device '430841b9'
[2014-06-13 12:06:39 - Foracles] Installing Foracles.apk...
[2014-06-13 12:06:43 - Foracles] Success!
[2014-06-13 12:06:44 - Foracles] \Foracles\bin\Foracles.apk installed on device
[2014-06-13 12:06:44 - Foracles] Done!
```

I had used my device recently on another project but it doesn't have the condition like this wherein it installs the apk on my device but it doesn't show up or run automatically.

Comment: did you declare your activity in manifest? Your manifest shows no activities or specify the main activity?

Comment: Refer to aniruddha's answer below, it shows how to declare your manifest. This is the problem most newbies face, manifest.xml is the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `activity` registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`. That is why it is showing

```
Foracles] Installing Foracles.apk...
Foracles] Success!
Foracles] \Foracles\bin\Foracles.apk installed on device
Foracles] Done!
```

If it had any activity then the message will be something like `Launching your activity with Intetnt`.

Actually your application is installed on device but you're not able to see anything because it doesn't have any activities registered.

So you need to register your `activity` in `Manifest` inside `application` tag.

Like

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <activity android:name = "packagename.classname" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>
```

Comment: Thanks :). You can up vote and encourage a newbie like me to answer more.

Comment: Sure my man - i shall upvote, your answer was better than mine. I only pointed to the problem and you posted proper code :)

Comment: Okay okay thanks. But one more i added 
<activity android:name = "com.main.Main" >
      </activity>
What should i put in the intent?